# How to insert values in a table from a view

Tags: sql-server, view, insert, sql-update, case

I have a view from which I have to insert values in a table. The view is as:

```
Author_ID   Research_Area   Category    Paper_Count Paper_Year  Rank
--------------------------------------------------------------------
677         feature         8           1           2005        1
677         image           11          1           2005        2
677         retrieval       12          1           2005        3
677         semantic        19          1           2007        1
677         feature         8           1           2009        1
677         video           5           2           2013        1
1359        image           11          2           2005        1
1359        adversary       1           1           2005        2
1359        archiving       12          1           2005        3
1359        linear          1           3           2006        1
1359        real time       17          3           2006        2
...  
...
```

And the Table is as:

```
id   Author_ID   Category_2005   Category_2006   Category_2007.....Category_2014   Rank
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have to insert each `Author_ID` and each `Author_ID` has three values for `Category` column according to rank for each `Paper_Year`, some `Author_ID`'s may not having values for some of `Paper_Year` so have to insert `0` for `Paper_Year`s having no `Category` value, whereas each `Author_ID` should get displayed only `3` times in resultant table.

I have tried this for only `Paper_Year` i.e. `2005` as:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.aid       =   (SELECT vA.Author_ID 
                     FROM Author_Area vA 
                     WHERE vA.Paper_Year = 2005 AND vA.Rank = 1),
A.Category_2005 =   (SELECT vA.Category 
                     FROM Author_Area vA 
                     WHERE vA.Paper_Year = 2005 AND vA.Rank = 1)
FROM Author_Areas A
```

But unable to update any rows in table. So should I use to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` in this scenario and do `CASE` statements may be used, if so then how?

Moreover, my output in resultant table should be like this:

```
id   Category_2005   Category_2006   Category_2007 ...   Category_2014   Rank
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
677  8               0               19                  0               1
677  11              0               0                   0               2
677  12              0               0                   0               3
1359 11              1               0                   1               1
1359 1               17              0                   0               2
1359 12              0               10                  0               3
...
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to create new rows in the table? 
Also, I assume `id` column is a primary key `IDENTITY` column?

You simply want to find a way to pivot (which is [actually a language feature](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)).  In this case, it's relatively easy to write without using the `PIVOT` syntax, and simply use filtered aggregations (`MAX` with `CASE` inside).

```
INSERT INTO Author_Areas (
  ID,
  Category_2005,
  Category_2006,
  Category_2007,
  Category_2008,
  Category_2009,
  Category_2010,
  Category_2011,
  Category_2012,
  Category_2013,
  Category_2014,
  Rank
)
SELECT Author_ID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Paper_Year = 2005 THEN category ELSE 0 END),
  MAX(CASE WHEN Paper_Year = 2006 THEN category ELSE 0 END),
  MAX(CASE WHEN Paper_Year = 2007 THEN category ELSE 0 END),
  MAX(CASE WHEN Paper_Year = 2008 THEN category ELSE 0 END),
  MAX(CASE WHEN Paper_Year = 2009 THEN category ELSE 0 END),
  MAX(CASE WHEN Paper_Year = 2010 THEN category ELSE 0 END),
  MAX(CASE WHEN Paper_Year = 2011 THEN category ELSE 0 END),
  MAX(CASE WHEN Paper_Year = 2012 THEN category ELSE 0 END),
  MAX(CASE WHEN Paper_Year = 2013 THEN category ELSE 0 END),
  MAX(CASE WHEN Paper_Year = 2014 THEN category ELSE 0 END),
  Rank
FROM
  Author_Area
GROUP BY
  Author_ID, Rank
```

Comment: You need to describe what you want to do with those values.  Your example query simply ignores them, so my solution does also.

Comment: I've updated my answer to insert one row per rank, per author.

Comment: @Jeff--I have displayed the resultant table, how it should look like

Comment: @Jeff--"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Author_Areas' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF." this is the error whereas my Identity Specification is set to Yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96955/discussion-between-jeff-meatball-yang-and-taufel).